# ¿Porqué no ocurre nada si usamos dato estático en función no estática?

Tags: c++, poo

un dato declarado como estático dentro de una clase, en un programa que estoy usando lo devuelve o asigna en dos funciones y ninguna es static, cuando en teoría, si queremos usar un datos estático en una función, esta función debe ser estática ¿no?
¿Por qué el compilador no dice nada cuando usamos un dato estático en un método no estático? ¿Debería protestar pero porqué no lo hace?

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un código de ejemplo de lo que estás preguntando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es al revés: desde una función estática, **no puedes** acceder a variables no-estáticas. Pero, desde funciones no-estáticas, **es perfectamente válido** acceder a variables estáticas.

Las rázones *reales* de este comportamiento son las siguientes:

- Una función no-estática recibe un primer argumento *oculto*, llamado `this`. Ese argumento es un puntero a la instancia sobre la que operamos.
- Una función estática **no recibe** el argumento `this`, pues que por su propia definición de `static` estamos indicando que no lo queremos.
- Cualquier cosa `static` **no está asociada** a ninguna instancia; su posición en memoria no cambia durante toda la vida del programa, y es conocida por el compilador en todo momento.

Ahora ya está todo claro:

1. Desde funciones `static` **no puedes** acceder a nada que necesite `this`, porque no lo tenemos: ni a variables, ni a funciones.
2. Desde funciones no-státicas, podemos acceder a cualesquiera variables y funciones de la clase:

   - Disponemos de `this`, por lo que podemos acceder a la instancia.
   - Las variables-miembro `static` **no necesitan** `this`, y son siempre accesibles.

Comment: Gracias compañero, muy aclaratorio, lo entiendo. Eso sí, el segundo punto que pones, te has debido sin querer equivocar, en realidad querrías decir que una función estática no recibe el argumento this. Corrígelo que al modificar menos de 6 caracteres eliminando el no, no me deja modificarla jejeje Gracias por todo @Trauma

Comment: ¡ Huy ! Cierto. Corregido :-)

Comment: Gracias siempre por tu ayuda, que no es poca :) Un saludo compañero @Trauma